# Why do I get NoMethodError: undefined method `rescue' for #<Concurrent::Future:...>?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rescue

Ruby's Concurrent::Future was not catching the exceptions. So I copied the code from an [article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/using-concurrent-ruby-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application) to add a `rescue` block.
But now I got the error:

> Caused by NoMethodError: undefined method `rescue' for #Concurrent::Future:0x0000000124764268

Here is the code:

```rb
executed_future = Concurrent::Future.execute do
            url = "#{endpoint}#{datum[:hierarchy_id]}#{valuation_date}"
            raise StandardError.new("Testing error!") # To test

            [...]
          end.rescue do | exception | # Adding this, will throw the error
            @exceptions << exception
            binding.pry # No activated
          end
```

What am I missing?

I expect to rescue exceptions in the `Concurrent::Future` block. Just like the article does.

Comment: What version of `Concurrent`?

Comment: `concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)`

Comment: Rescue is not a method; you can't chain it to a block. It's part of the Ruby grammar to catch exceptions, and belongs *inside* your block.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `Concurrent::Future` and I might miss a that there exists a different implementation of a `rescue` method in that specific gem.

But in Ruby `rescue` is not a method that you call on the return value of another method (like the return value of the `Concurrent::Future.execute` call in your question). It is a keyword that catches exception raise in the context of the current block.

Therefore, I would try using the idiomatic Ruby `begin ... rescue ... end` syntax within the `Concurrent::Future.execute` block:

```
executed_future = Concurrent::Future.execute do
  begin
    url = "#{endpoint}#{datum[:hierarchy_id]}#{valuation_date}"
    raise StandardError.new("Testing error!") # To test
    # ...
  rescue StandardError => exception
    @exceptions << exception
    binding.pry
  end
end
```